# Print new message from the list once object is created

Tags: python, oop

I have a parent class Character and inherit classes Warrior, Sorcerer, Drood.
Each time, new warrior creates as an object, I need to print the next message form defined list, if there are no more sentences, just go back to the first one.

The print function should be in Character class, not in Warrior - condition.

I would be happy if you can explain to me the approach itself and maybe, advise what to read. Pure answers are also welcome but would be happy to find the solution in the end. Thank you!

```
class Character:

    def __init__(self, life_points, name, hair_color):
        self.life_points = life_points
        self.name = name
        self.hair_color = hair_color
        print(self.__class__.welcome_words) # "welcome_words" should receive the actual sentence for the list "welcome_words_list"

class Warrior(Character):
    welcome_words_list = ["Grrr!", "AAAAAAA", "BBBBBBB", "CCCCCCC", "DDDDDDD"]

class Sorcerer(Character):
    welcome_words_list = ["Baboo!", "FFFFFFF", "GGGGGG", "HHHHHHH", "IIIIIIII"]

class Drood(Character):
    welcome_words_list = ["WoooWaaa!", "JJJJJJJ", "KKKKKKK", "LLLLLLL", "MMMMMMM"]

my_warrior = Warrior(80, "Kartman", "red")
my_warrior1 = Warrior(80, "David", "green")
my_warrior2 = Warrior(80, "Kate", "blue")

my_sorcerer = Sorcerer(80, "Lucia", "brown")
my_sorcerer1 = Sorcerer(80, "Mark", "yellow")
my_sorcerer2 = Sorcerer(80, "Smith", "brown")

my_drood = Drood(80, "Boby", "blue")
my_drood1 = Drood (80, "Jenifer", "green")
my_drood2 = Drood (80, "Sam", "red")
```

I can't understand how to change the message of new created object each time it gets created.

Comment: In `Character` define `welcome_words = None` as class attribute and override it in subclasses e.g. `welcome_words = itertools.cycle(["Grrr!", "AAAAAAA", "BBBBBBB", "CCCCCCC", "DDDDDDD"])`. In `Character.__init__()` write `print(next(self.welcome_words))`.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! `itertools` can help here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**: Each time, a new `Character` object is created, I need to print the `next` message from a list of words, defined in the subclass, e.g. `Warrior`.

To share a object with all instantiated objects from the same class, you can use `class objects`.
To cycle infinite, the list of words, there is the function `cycle` in the `itertools` module.

---

- [9.3.2. Class Objects - class variable](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)

  > A variable that is defined in a class level (not in an instance of the class), that is shared by all instances of a class.
- [itertools.cycle(iterable)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)

  > Make an iterator returning elements from the iterable. Repeats indefinitely.

---

```
import itertools


class Character:
    def __init__(self, life_points, name):
        self.life_points = life_points
        self.name = name

        # "welcome_words" 
        print('{}'.format((life_points, name, 
                           self.__class__.__name__, 
                           next(self.WORD_LIST))))


class Warrior(Character):
    WORD_LIST = itertools.cycle(
        ("Grrr!", "AAAAAAA", "BBBBBBB", "CCCCCCC", "DDDDDDD"))


class Sorcerer(Character):
    WORD_LIST = itertools.cycle(
        ("Baboo!", "FFFFFFF", "GGGGGG", "HHHHHHH", "IIIIIIII"))


name = ("Kartman", "David", "Kate")
for n in range(1, 11):
    Warrior(n, name[int(n % 3)])
    Sorcerer(n, name[int(n % 3)])
```

> **Output**:
>
> ```
> (1, 'David', 'Warrior', 'Grrr!')
> (1, 'David', 'Sorcerer', 'Baboo!')
> (2, 'Kate', 'Warrior', 'AAAAAAA')
> (2, 'Kate', 'Sorcerer', 'FFFFFFF')
> (3, 'Kartman', 'Warrior', 'BBBBBBB')
> (3, 'Kartman', 'Sorcerer', 'GGGGGG')
> (4, 'David', 'Warrior', 'CCCCCCC')
> (4, 'David', 'Sorcerer', 'HHHHHHH')
> (5, 'Kate', 'Warrior', 'DDDDDDD')
> (5, 'Kate', 'Sorcerer', 'IIIIIIII')
> (6, 'Kartman', 'Warrior', 'Grrr!')
> (6, 'Kartman', 'Sorcerer', 'Baboo!')
> (7, 'David', 'Warrior', 'AAAAAAA')
> (7, 'David', 'Sorcerer', 'FFFFFFF')
> (8, 'Kate', 'Warrior', 'BBBBBBB')
> (8, 'Kate', 'Sorcerer', 'GGGGGG')
> (9, 'Kartman', 'Warrior', 'CCCCCCC')
> (9, 'Kartman', 'Sorcerer', 'HHHHHHH')
> (10, 'David', 'Warrior', 'DDDDDDD')
> (10, 'David', 'Sorcerer', 'IIIIIIII')
> ```

***Tested with Python: 3.6***

Comment: This is very close to what I wanted to do. Thank you!